Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents()
se tiene un problema en un sitio que inicia sesión que es el siguiente:
Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'ErrorException' with message 'file_put_contents(): Only 0 of 170 bytes written, possibly out of free disk space' in /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/log/file.php:91 Stack trace: #0 [internal function]: Kohana_Core::error_handler(2, 'file_put_conten...', '/var/www/html/s...', 91, Array) #1 /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/log/file.php(91): file_put_contents('/var/www/html/a...', '\n2024-05-16 08:...', 8) #2 /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/log.php(183): Kohana_Log_File->write(Array) #3 /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/session.php(371): Kohana_Log->write() #4 [internal function]: Kohana_Session->write() #5 {main} thrown in /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/log/file.php on line 91

se entiende que es problema de espacio, pero se realizo un cambio de servidor a uno más grande y continua el problema, busque y no he encontrado respuesta de como poder corregirlo.
agradeceria cualquier ayuda :(
esta es la linea 91 que indica el php
    file_put_contents($filename, PHP_EOL.$message['time'].' --- '.$this->_log_levels[$message['level']].': '.$message['body'], FILE_APPEND);```


En que usan file_put_contents() en un login?

en la secccion de login
https://i.postimg.cc/mkxP7HSx/ERP.jpg

Si, pero file_put_contents() es una función similar a llamar fopen(), fwrite(), y fclose() y es para escribir datos en un archivo. La pregunta mía era sobre que tendrá que ver el login con un archivo?? Pueda que no vea el contexto del uso...

primero que nada te recomiendo que hagas el [tour], segundo es importante que muestres el codigo citado por el error, asi como parece estar relacionado al espacio no has demostrado nada que nos diga que has evaluado... decir que evaluaste si hay espacio no nos dice el que evaluaste o como lo evaluaste...

decir que migraste a un servidor nuevo ... no nos dice nada ... ya que las instalaciones nueva de los sistema operativos no usan todo el disco duro a menos que asi lo hayas configurado un clasico error en debian y ubuntu, entonces de ser este el problema tendrias que preguntar en https://superuser.com/

Puede ser permisos tambien

@Duston, me podrias indicar como ver el tema de los permisos?
la migración se realizo hace poco, en el uso de disco indica que queda mas del 50% libre, se limpiaron los caches y la carpeta de logs, pero al yo no haber programado esto me tiene aproblemado

Para ver los permiso de la carpeta, intenta  ll /var/www/html/system/classes/kohana/log/  Es posible que sea solament para leer y no se permita escribir.  Hay muchas páginas donde puede leer como interpretar los rwx de linux.

los permisos que tiene son 777.... y en el file.php que dice el error tiene 02777 ( no me ha dejado editar para agregar el php)

¿puedes pegar la linea 91 de file.php en la pregunta?  al menos así veremos donde se intenta guardar ese archivo con el file_put_contents() y ver más contexto de lo que esta sucediendo, pues vamos a ciegas completamente sin más pistas.

se agrego la linea 91

Pues si no es mucha molestia ahora agrega lo que es $filename para que veamos donde está apuntando realmente, pues con solo la variable no soy capaz de abstraer suficientemente el problema, pues puede ser cualquier cosa

¿Limpiaste el caché en tu nuevo servidor? Si usas algún framework para este proyecto, tipo Symfony, Laravel, u otro, conviene mencionarlo en la pregunta.
